# How do I wait for a value to be retrieved from API calls. Before starting my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

Supposed I have a json object from a url.

```
fetch(URL, setting)
.then(loadRes)
.then(logger)


function loadRes (res){
  return res.json();
}
```

Not sure whether `async` is needed right below.

```
async function logger (reply){
  let stringReply = await reply.answer;
  console.log("Obtain value " + stringReply) //let the value be a string e.g "apple"

  sendingReply(stringReply);

  return stringReply
}
```

Using express

```
app.post('/', function( req, res){

    console.log(sendingReply()) 
}
```

when i tried logging the results again, it shows `promise { <pending> }`
So how can I retrieved the value from the earlier on. *Waiting for the value to be retrieved*

Correct me if I'm wrong, my understanding is that when the code is being run, it execute everything at once. So therefore by the time I received a result from the URL link *(json object)*, it is already done executing it.

Comment: what is `reply.answer` it looks like a property and not a method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `reply.answer` is a resolved promise, then only await would be required. Since you've mentioned it is returning `Promise { <pending> }`, I guess it would be an unresolved `Promise` which gives a pending state.

`x=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>("vre"))   //gives Promise {<pending>}`

`x=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>resolve("vre"))   //gives Promise {<resolved>: "vre"}`

I hope that resolves your concern.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using `await` then `async` function is required and in this case correctly used. However, `await` has to be used before a promise call.

What does `reply.answer` return? if it returns a promise then `reply.answer()` is the correct way to call that function.

2. Please let know your output error message, also let me know what's the purpose on `sendingReply()`, it's supposed to return a promise? does it return a value?